# How do I prevent active state in navigation from creating space when zooming?

Tags: css

I'd like to figure out how to prevent this current-state triangle cut out from showing spaces in between the notch and the nav when zooming in and out.

http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/ZDNu7/21/

Why is `.current` not keeping the same design at 100% zoom, as it is with 90% or 75% or pretty much any zoom % other than 100%?

Edit: for clarity

I am trying to avoid these spaces from appearing in the notched navigation when zooming: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtn05.jpg

Edit: in bootstrap

Need it to work zooming in/out in bootstrap.

Comment: seems calculated result between `:after`'s border and `:before`'s width are not the same. Same as `bottom: 0` :o weird

Comment: Question is not clear to me can you tell me more clearly what you want to do are you saying that you dont want your notch to be positioned how and where ?

Comment: @SachinDivakar these spaces should not appear when zooming in and out: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dtn05.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works in Bootstrap.

Remove these "1px"s:

```
.nav .current a:after {
   border:1em solid; /* Half of our magic number. */
   border-color:#fff #fff transparent #fff;
   width: 1px;
   height: 1px;
}
```

So it's like this:

http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/mEVqBb

```
.nav .current a:after{
   border:1em solid; /* Half of our magic number. */
   border-color:#fff #fff transparent #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [these spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtn05.jpg) appearing while zooming, it can be solved by setting:

`.nav .current a:after {
   width: 1px;
   height: 1px;
}`

[Edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49xL36o9/)

If this isn't what you ment, please specify.

Comment: When you are in 67%, it still exist. `em` not calculated correctly in these element(`:after`, `:before`).

Comment: Hmm.. this doesn't seem to work right when zooming in/out with same nav placed in bootstrap: http://codepen.io/Goatsy/pen/JKGYoZ (but yes, you are correct that this space is what i'm referring to)